# Making a drawing application using swing and mouse listener

Tags: java, swing

i have an assignment to make a simple drawing application using swing and mouse listener. the application has to have three classes, one that contains Main, one that contains the frame, and the last one that makes the drawing. The teacher gave us a source code we're supposed to use to complete the assignment and it looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Drawsome extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {


public Drawsome(){
    setSize(300,400);
    setForeground(Color.black);     
    show();;
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}



 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
   start = end;
   end = new Point(evt.getX(),evt.getY());
   repaint();
 }

 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {  
  end = null;
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     if (start!=null  && end!=null)
     g.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);

 }


 public void update(Graphics g) {
     paint(g);
 }


Point start=null;
Point end=null;

}
```

now this work perfectly, but since we have to make the frame in another class i tried to do this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public  MainWindow() {

        setSize(300,400);
        setForeground(Color.black);     
        show();;        

    }

}


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Drawsome extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {


public Drawsome(){
MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();

addMouseMotionListener(this);
} (rest is the same as the previous code)
```

i'll get a frame, but the rest doesn't work, i dont' understand what i'm doing wrong, and would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher's source code is terrible since you should never be drawing within the paint method or within a JFrame, plus his/her paint override doesn't call the super's method, breaking the painting chain. They don't appear to know what they're doing.

Having said that, your main driver should not extend JFrame nor should you try to create a JFrame of it or even an instance of it. Instead, in this class's main method, create an instance of the terrible drawing class.

Note that I don't understand this requirement:

> and the last one that makes the drawing.

Please post the **exact** requirements.

---

If this were my application, I'd

- Do my drawing within a JPanel, and not a JFrame
- Do it within the JPanel's `paintComponent` method, not the paint method.
- Be sure to call the super's `paintComponent` method within my JPanel's `paintComponent` method override.
- Then place my JPanel within a JFrame to display it.
- I would not have my GUI class implement the MouseListener but rather would use a nested inner class for this.

Comment: i had to translate this to english so may be a bit iffy.

make a entry point for a main window in swing. the main window have to contain a panel that lets the user draw with use of the mouse pointer.

use the code from the class Drawsome in the simplest way you can handle.

do the assignment as simple as possible with as little code as possible.

complete the assignment with exactly three classes.

the three classes shall be named
*drawing application
*mainwindow
*drawsome

the class drawsome is going to be the entry point

Comment: @JeanFredrikLeirtrø: I would give DrawSome the static main method, and that's it. I'd give MainWindow the JFrame, and I'd have DrawingApplication extend JPanel and do the drawing within it's paintComponent method.

Comment: i'm sorry the class DrawingApplication is going to be the entry point, so main has to be there